# Multiple TCP connection on same IP and port

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

I have a very basic question about TCP.

Consider an application, say `DEST`, with IP `Dest IP` listening on port 6789.

Now I have 2 source applications which are capable of sending messages to this application `DEST` and they communicate via TCP protocol.

Say source system 1 is `SRC1` and source system 2 is `SRC2` with IPs `SRC1` and `SRC2` respectively.

Ideally only one of these source systems would be running and I can see that I have an active connection between `SRC1` or `SRC2` and `DEST` by executing the `netstat` command on the source system (`netstat -nao | grep 6789`).

Now just for heck of it I started the second source system as well and was surprised to learn that the result of `netstat` on both the source systems shows an active TCP connection with the application `DEST` listening on port 6789.

Result of `netstat` command on `SRC1` and `SRC2` servers:

```
TCP SRC1 IP:17678   DEST IP: 6789 ESTABLISHED

TCP SRC2 IP:51298   DEST IP: 6789 ESTABLISHED
```

I was under the impression that `DEST` application listening on IP `DEST1` and Port 6789 can only have 1 active TCP connection (`DEST` server `IP:6789` can have only 1 active TCP connection).

Comment: Whatever made you think that?!

Answer (score 10):

If what you thought were true, web servers wouldn't work.  Web servers basically listen on two ports: 80 for HTTP, and 443 for HTTPS.  Web servers often have many thousands of clients connected at once.

The application can have many connections through one port.  It can distinguish the connections by the source/port combination of the connecting host.  In fact, each source host could have connections on multiple ports (the address is really a combination of address and port) to the same destination port, if the application supports it.

Answer (score 9):

A TCP connection is defined by a 4-tuple:  local IP, local port, remote IP, remote port.  Note that I didn't say source and destination because once the connection is established there is no distinction.

In the example you gave, the two connections had one IP and port in common, but the other IP and port were different.

This is different than a TCP listening socket which is defined only by the local IP and port.  What that means is that only one socket can listen for new connections on a given port.  Once a connection is made you have a new socket defined by the 4-tuple mentioned above, although all connections originating from a given listening socket will have the same local IP and port but different remote IPs and/or ports.

Comment: and what if Source/Dest IP and Ports are same? Say an example of Multiple Tabs opened in a browser getting data form same server?

Comment: @Saad they can’t all be the same.  In a situation like that, you’ll have multiple sockets with the same source and dest IPs, and the port on the server side will be the same, but the client side ports will be different for each.

Comment: So if UDP is being managed, still different sockets in some kind of same scenario?

Comment: @Saad UDP is different.  A UDP socket only has a local port and IP since there is no connection.

Comment: Is it at sender side or receiver side

Answer (score 0):

A Server listens for new connection requests on a port. On a request, it accepts the connection and uses a new established port to connect to the remote client. The actual communication happens between these 2 ports and the listening port still keeps polling for new connections.